# How do I @copydoc from an object with spaces in its name?

Tags: doxygen

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc

made some exclamatory mention of not using spaces in your @copydoc directive.

But what do you do when the source of the copy is an object that inherently contains spaces, such as:

```
class Base
{
public:
    /**
     * True if blah blah blah
     */
    virtual operator bool() const = 0;

    /**
     * Messages about any rules that were broken
     */
    virtual const std::vector<Err> & errors() const = 0;
...

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    /*! @copydoc Base::operator bool()
     * This doesn't work.
     */
    operator bool() const;

    /*! @copydoc Base::errors()
     * This does work.
     */
    const std::vector<Err> & errors() const;
...
```

I also tried

```
/*! @copydoc SomeOtherClass::operatorbool()
```

and

```
/*! @copydoc SomeOtherclass::bool()
```

just as random guesses, but neither worked.

Comment: Note that if the object pointed to is a member (function, variable, typedef, etc), the compound (class, file, or group) containing it should also be documented for the copying to work.

Did you read this? Maybe you should provide you full documentantion, so that we can recreate the problem.

Comment: And judging from the description, what you are saying about spaces is only true for the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I provided what I've got, with names changed to protect the innocent :)

Comment: Please provide some info in the end, on how you solved it etc etc as I'm curious

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this by defining the virtual method as follows:

```
virtual operatorbool()const = 0;
```

also you'll need this in your derived class:

```
/*! @copydoc Base::operatorbool
 *  random info here
 */
```

This is a possible bug, maybe this needs a ticket, unless I'm missing something...

This worked for `doxygen 1.8.6`.